# What Microcontroller(s) is/are used inside the ECU of a CF6-80C2 engine?

Tags: engine

The question came up at work today and no one knew the answer. Did some digging online and could not find anything definitive.

Comment: That information could be a trade secret, therefore not likely to be public.

Comment: Don't know for sure so can't post this as an answer, but given the age of the design I'd say the probability is high it uses an Intel 8086 microprocessor.  There is usually a command and a monitor channel running together in these sorts of units, the monitor channel mimicking everything the command one does to detect anomalies, and often monitor channel might use a Motorola equivalent like a 68000 to mitigate the risks of a processor architecture related defect causing both channels to see the same flaw and not see anything wrong.